# Problems with jQuery internals, fn.bind/fn.apply on draggables (trying to do better exception handling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

I'm been trying to wrap javascript try/catch as seen on http://pastebin.com/f579d999d

It works well, it basically wrap everything in a try/catch letting you catch errors like this:

```
$.handleErrors(function(e){
    console.log("an error occurred");
    console.log(e);
});
```

(and then I'm going to post it to server)

However, this does not work for draggables or resizables (but for everything else). If you start to drag/resize an element, it doesn't stop on mouse up (making the drag forever)

It appears as if the ofn.apply() doesn't work on draggable/resizable.

Specifically (shortened):

> ```
>           ofn = fn;
>           wfn = function() {
>                 ofn.apply(this, arguments);
>           };
>           fn = wfn;
> ```

But for all other events.

Code block):

> ```
>      $.fn.bind = function(type, data, fn) {
>        var ofn, wfn;
>        if (!fn && data && $.isFunction(data)) {
>           fn = data;
>            data = undefined;
>       }
>        if (fn && type.indexOf("error") === -1) {
>           ofn = fn;
>           wfn = function() {
>              try {
>                 ofn.apply(this, arguments);
>              } catch(e) {
>                 handler(e);
>                 return false;
>              }
>           };
>           fn = wfn;
>        }
>        return jbind.call(this, type, data, fn);
> ```

I'm pretty much lost here, and I can't find any resource saying why this shouldn't work (I can't even find anyone who has the same issues)

So my question is:

1. Does the above method seem like an OK way to catch errors with jQuery
2. Has anyone experienced the same issue (and fixed it)
3. Do I misunderstand something and I should simply not call this on draggable events

Regards,
Niklas

Update 2011-08-28, the full code (working) is now:

```
jQuery.fn.bind = function( type, data, fn ) { 
    if ( !fn && data && typeof data == 'function' ) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
    }

    if ( fn )
    {
        var origFn = fn;
        var wrappedFn = jQuery.proxy(origFn, function () { 
            try {
                origFn.apply( this, arguments );
            }catch ( ex ) {
                return trackError( ex );
           }
        });
        fn = wrappedFn;
    }
    return jQueryBind.call( this, type, data, fn );
};
```

If anyone has more tips on how to improve it (the original function is from http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/04/javascript-error-tracking-why-windowonerror-is-not-enough.html) please let me know in a comment.

Comment: I've setup a demo on http://bivald.com/jquerydraggable.html (working on click, not working on drag) - I'm testing everything in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: 1 - We do the same thing, and it seems to work pretty well.

Re: 2 - Yes.  What's happening is jQuery UI isn't able to unbind "mousemove.draggable" once you wrap the original function.  The fix is to add the line below (adapted from jQuery's proxy function):

```
// Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed
wfn.guid = ofn.guid = ofn.guid || wfn.guid || jQuery.guid++;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, found a second solution as well, to use jQuery.proxy `var wrappedFn = jQuery.proxy(origFn, function () { `

Comment: Jamey, if you are the commenter on http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/04/javascript-error-tracking-why-windowonerror-is-not-enough.html (with the same profile picture), could you share the complete code, including the return fix?

Comment: Oh, good to know. Then I'm using your function instead. Again, thank you!